# Background Work - Service, Thread or Both

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, handler

So I am developing an Android app that gets data from a website as part of its process.  Some of that data is images.  I want to cache the data.  I know I need to do this in the background but am confused how to go about this.  I want the background part to be accessible from every activity.  I think I need to put this functionality into a service running in the background.  Do I also need to make a new thread or can I do that implicitly in the service?

I have read about using Handler and Looper.  Do these need to be integrated into the service?  Or should I just use those?

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't really clear.  I want to get data from the webpage that will be displayed on my device.  I found an example of "Lazy List" image loading that looks promising but had some drawbacks.  It set up a queue of images it downloaded one at a time and then updated the list view.  it was just a Thread though.

It seems like making a new one of these for each image would be a little pointless.  I'm trying to modify it to allow access from multiple activities.  I also want to use the proper constructs.  From reading it seems like Looper and Handler were designed for this.

Comment: What do you mean by cache? Why not just place them in a static map, and back it up by writing information to external storage? How much data are we talking about?

Comment: They should be pretty small images mainly.  But they come from the web and may accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have several requirements:

1. Cache a moderate amount data from the internet
2. Get this data dynamically in the background
3. Use this data across multiple activities
4. Be able to handle multiple concurrent requests

Point 2 suggests you need a separate thread if you don't want to impact the performance of the UI thread. Point 3 suggests you need a Service. Point 1 and 4 suggest that some sort of queue might be useful.

The one class that combines all of these is the [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). Take a look at that. It basically queues and handles requests in the background on a worker thread. Since it's all internet data, you can just pass it an Intent with a URI, and you can have the `IntentService` do the downloading for you. You probably want to pass in a [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) with the intent so that when the download completes, you can signal back to the activity that you've finished that URI.

Comment: This is almost ideal for me and in general is the answer.  However after looking around I have decided to use a service with a Handler and Looper so I can control priority and have a little more control.

Comment: That's certainly reasonable. If you take a look at the `IntentService` implementation it's exactly what you outlined: a service with a handler and a looper.

Comment: It doesn't let you manage what tasks run in what order though.

Comment: Yeah, I was just agreeing that implementing it yourself that way is reasonable if you have more requirements that the IntentService can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is your specific use case. If you want to preload some images to be available regardless of whether your application is visible or not, you should consider service.

However, if you just want to cache images that are loaded in your current activity, `AsyncTask`may be a better choice.

In both cases, you probably want to store your cached images in persistent store (cache directory or SQLLite), so it will be available to any of your activities.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how "background" you want the process to be. If you want to get the data from the website without the user even knowing about it, you should use a `Service` + `AsyncTask` (you still need the `AsyncTask` because, by default, the `Service` is run in the same thread/process as the UI -- so if you do any long-running tasks without a separate thread you'll block the UI thread and it will be quite nasty).

However, this approach will lead to other headaches. For example, you'll have to find a way to start your service -- either use the `AlarmManager` to start it regularly, or find some other mechanism (listen for a broadcast intent, for example).

A different approach would be to load the data in an `Activity`, while showing the user a loading message (you might want to look into `ProgressDialog`). This way the user knows what you're doing and you can very simply implement a "refresh" feature.

In both cases, you have quite a few storage options. You can:

- store the files you retrieve directly to the cache dir / sdcard (check out `getCacheDir()` on `Context`)
- in case you do parsing (JSON / XML for example) you can store serialized objects to the cache dir / sdcard so you don't have to parse them again
- you can use an sqlite database (there are docs and tutorials on the android dev site)

Then, you can use the stored data in any of your application components (activities, services, etc.)